# using do loop for a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I had posted this earlier, and got help on it.  My interest was piqued, and I ventured into this a little further to see what I could do with it.  I am fascinated with simulations, but am just an average SAS programmer.  I wonder if somebody might help here.

```
data out;
  call streaminit(7);           *seed better random number engine;
  do pointvar = 1 by 1 until (outs=27);   *iterate starting at         
  1 and stop when 27 outs ;
    randvar = rand('Uniform');  *better random number engine;
    if pointvar > 9 then pointvar=1;      *reset to 1 if over 9;
    set in point=pointvar;      *pull the row we need;
    if randvar < cutoff then do;
      outs+1;
      outs_inning+1;
    end;
    output;
    if outs_inning=3 then outs_inning=0;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

the data set has just one observation for the 9 hitters.

.73
.75
.72
.78
.81
.69
.74
.72
.75

With the help of Joe and others, the above did what I wanted, which was to simulate primarily the counting of outs involved in ONE baseball game.

I have been playing around with this (to no avail) and trying to get it to repeat a game, so to speak, where it would start at the top of the lineup after 27 outs. So for what I have right now, assume the 27th out is achieved with the 5th batter. I would like to put this whole code inside of a loop where it starts the process again at the beginning of the data set (1st observation, i.e, first batter).
So, assume I want to complete 3 iterations here. 3 games of 27 outs. Is there a way to do this? I tried doing the following.

```
%macro replicate(new,out,n)/des=’&new1 is &out repeated &n times 

Data &new; 

%do i=1 to &n; 

  Set &out; 

Output; 

%end; 

%mend; 

%replicate(new,out,3); 

Proc print;
```

I was hoping with a do statement I could do this, but The problem with this is that it is reading each observation 3 times. So in the do i=1 to 3, followed by set out (three instances it takes the first observation from data set ‘out’, then 3 times it takes the second observation from data set out, etc.
 i.e.

Outs   randvar   cutoff    outs_inning

0      0.84           0.73      0

0      0.84           0.73      0

0      0.84           0.73      0

1      0.61           0.75      0

1      0.61           0.75      0

1      0.61           0.75      0

Can anybody help?  I appreciate that this is a little outside the realm of what is typically discussed here, but a few of my students are also interested in simulations, and a baseball example has certainly interested them.  It has become a fun problem.  thanks for getting me this far.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro.  You should be able to add an outer DO loop which is `do game=1 to 3;`

Below I changed the variable POINTVAR to be BATTER, and added a PUT statement to write messages to the log.

```
data in;
  input cutoff @@;
  cards;
.73 .75 .72 .78 .81 .69 .74 .72 .75
;

data play;
  call streaminit(7);

  do game=1 to 3;
    outs=0; 
    outs_inning=0;
    do batter = 1 by 1 until (outs=27);
      randvar = rand('Uniform');
      if batter > 9 then batter=1;
      set in point=batter;
      if randvar < cutoff then do;
        outs+1;
        outs_inning+1;
      end;
      output;
      put (game batter cutoff randvar outs_inning outs)(=);
      if outs_inning=3 then outs_inning=0;
    end;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```